# $\Delta (u^m)=\mathrm{div}(m u^{m-1} \mathrm{grad}(u))$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives, fractional-sobolev-spaces

How can one show that for a suitable $u$ the weak laplacian

$\Delta (u^m)$ equals $\mathrm{div}(m u^{m-1} \mathrm{grad}(u))$ both in the weak sense ($m>1$)

and what conditions need one to impose on $u$ then?

Comment: Start with $\int u^m \cdot \Delta\phi$ for a test function $\phi$, and then try to integrate by parts. Where do you find difficulties?

Comment: But this does not lead anywhere, why can I use such thing like a chain rule on $u^m$? I assume that $u$ is in some suitable sobolev space but not smooth in general

Comment: you can prove a chain rule for $u^m$ for smooth functions, then argue by density

Comment: Thank you but I dont see how this is straight forward. I get that I need to show $\int_{\Omega} \phi (m u_n^m \partial_x u_n) \rightarrow \int_{\Omega} \phi (m u^m \partial_x u)$ but therefore I need to have that $m u_n^m \partial_x u_n $ converges in $L^1$ to $m u^m \partial_x u$ at least. And this is the part where I stuck

Comment: What space do you need $u$ to lie in?

Comment: @whpowell96 I think we need to assume that u is in $W^{2,m}(\Omega)$ so twice differentiable and derivatives in $L^m$